# Ratio limit of arithmetic means and integration

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

Let $n$ be a positive integer and $\varepsilon$ a small positive real number.
Suppose that $f(x) \in [0, 1]$ and $g(x) \in [0, 1]$ are continuos smooth functions defined $x \geq 0$, and satisfy $f(\infty) = g(\infty) = 0$, $\int_0^\infty f(x) \, dx < \infty$, and $\int_0^\infty g(x) \, dx < \infty$.

Is the following ratio correct?
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\left[
\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^n f(i \, \varepsilon)\right)
\bigg/
\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^n g(i \, \varepsilon)\right)\right]
=
\left(\int_0^\infty f(x) \, dx\right)
\Big/
\left(\int_0^\infty g(x) \, dx\right)
$$

Comment: You can't just assume $n$ and $\epsilon$ to go to their limits in the correct way. This may just as well converge to $f(0)/g(0)$ if we always take $\epsilon = \frac{1}{n^2}$ for example. It may not converge at all.

Comment: I removed $\varepsilon \to 0$, and assumed that $\varepsilon$ is a small positive real number.

Comment: Still no. Your limit doesn't even approach the integrals separately

Comment: A numerical example:
When $f(x) = 1/(1+x)^3$,
$g(x) = 1/(1+x)^5$,
we obtain $\int_0^\infty f(x) \, dx = 1/2$,
$\int_0^\infty g(x) \, dx = 1/4$.
Let $\varepsilon = 10^{-3}$, $n=10^6$,
then 
$
\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^n f(i \, \varepsilon)\right)
\big/
\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^n g(i \, \varepsilon)\right)
= 1.998
$, and

$
\left(\int_0^\infty f(x) \, dx\right)
\big/
\left(\int_0^\infty g(x) \, dx\right)
=2
$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 
$$
f(x)=\frac{\sin^2 \frac{\pi x}\varepsilon}{x^2+1},\ \ \ g(x)=\frac1{x^2+1}. 
$$
Then your left-hand-side is always zero, while the right-hand-side isn't.